# Removing rows from one file which do not mach another

Tags: bash, sorting, grep

I am looking for a efficient way to delete the rows in `file1` that do not exist in `file2` in bash:

file1.txt:

```
file1 <- 'probeset_id  sample1 sample2 sample3
AX-2           100     200    180
AX-1           90      180    267
AX-3           80      890    124'
file1 <- read.table(text=file1, header=T)
write.table(file1, "file1.txt", col.names=T, quote=F, row.names=F)
```

file2.txt:

```
file2 <- 'probeset_id
            AX-1
            AX-2  '
    file2 <- read.table(text=file2, header=T)
    write.table(file2, "file2.txt", col.names=F, quote=F, row.names=F)
```

The expected output:

```
out <- 'probeset_id  sample1 sample2 sample3
    AX-1           90      180    267
    AX-2           100     200    180'
    out <- read.table(text=out, header=T)
    write.table(out, "out.txt", col.names=T, quote=F, row.names=F)
```

The additional problem is that the `file2` is not sorted as `file1`. I am trying to use:

```
head -n 1 file1.txt ; grep -f file2.txt file1.txt
```

However, it is taking a long time. Any ideas to perform it in a more efficient way (the real files are quite big)?

Comment: `AX-2           100     200    180` doesn't exist in file2 so why is it in the expected output? How did `file1` become `out` etc.?

Comment: The AX-2 factor, however, do exist. The intention was to filter all rows in file1 based in which can be find in file2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` would be of great use in this case

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{line[$1]++; next}  $1 in line'
```

**Example**

```
$  awk 'NR==FNR{line[$1]++; next}  $1 in line' file2 file1
probeset_id  sample1 sample2 sample3
AX-2           100     200    180
AX-1           90      180    267
```

**What it does?**

- `NR==FNR{line[$1]++; next}` Saves the lines in `file2` in associative array `line` ( indexed by the first column )
- `NR==FNR` Is true for the first file in the list, `file2`.

  - `NR` Number or records read till now.
  - `FNR` Number of records read in the current file.
- `$1 in line` checks if the column 1 in `file1` is already saved in `line`, if true, `awk` takes the default action of printing the current records.